# insert string in string at index (swift)

Tags: html, swift, string, insert, substring

I've got a text which has some HTML tags in it. Something like this:

```
Lorem lipsum <a href="www.example.com"> lorem lipsum.
```

I want to insert the text `style=\"text-decoration: none\` right at the end of the HTML tag so that the link has no underline.

I've got a regex pattern that finds the HTML tag: `<\s*a[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*a>`

I have the following code to get the regex matches in the paragraph text and to calculate the position of the last character in the HTML tag:

```
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: paragraph.utf16.count)
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<\\s*a[^>]*>(.*?)<\\s*/\\s*a>")
let allMatches = regex.matches(in: paragraph, options: [], range: range)
let lastCharacter = allMatches[0].range.location + allMatches[0].range.length
```

How can I insert the string `style=\"text-decoration: none\` at that position?

I tried something like this:

```
let newParagraph = paragraph.insert(" style=\"text-decoration: none\"", at: lastCharacter)
```

However Xcode says that the first parameter in the `insert` method has to be a character, not a string.

Comment: Did you try the [insertString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablestring/1410999-insertstring?language=swift) method?

Comment: Is this an objective-c method? Xcode won't autocomplete this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my solution I use a regex finding everything between `<`and `>`to find the whole HTML tag. After the tag is found I use the `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)` method to

1. replace the closing tag’s bracket with the additional `style=` attribute (plus a closing bracket) to create the modified tag,
2. replace the original tag with the modified tag.

Here’s the code:

```
let string = "Lorem lipsum <a href=\"www.example.com\"> lorem lipsum <a href=\"www.somewhereelse.com\"> dolor sit amet."
let insertString = " style=\"text-decoration: none\">"
var modifiedString = string

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<.*?>")
let range = NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string)
let matches = regex.matches(in: string, range: range)
let tags = matches.map { String(string[Range($0.range, in: string)!]) }

for tag in tags {
    let newTag = tag.replacingOccurrences(of: ">", with: insertString)
    modifiedString = modifiedString.replacingOccurrences(of: tag, with: newTag)
}

print(modifiedString)
```

The updated code now uses a loop to replace all tags with the enhanced tags as per your requirement. For this to work you will have to change the regex to non-greedy: `<.*?>` instead of `<.*>`.

Comment: @WalterBeiter: Ok, I've just updated my code accordingly.

Comment: I tried implementing your code. I'Ve stumbled upon the short regex pattern. I only want this to happen for `<a>` tags – links in html. Thats why I had this longer regex pattern.

Comment: Sure. Just make sure your pattern is non-greedy so that you get an array of tags. So (without having tested) the pattern `<a.*?>` should do—or your pattern, of course ;-).

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help.

Comment: one last question: what exactly does this line of code do? `let tags = matches.map { String(string[Range($0.range, in: string)!]) }`

Comment: `matches` is an array of `NSTextCheckingResult` items returned from the regex queries. The `map` command traverses all array elements, exposing each element through the `$0` placeholder. So `$0.range` effectively means `<first regex match>.range`, `<second regex match>.range`, ...  `NSTextCheckingResult.range` yields the range of the regex match inside the search string. `String(...)` extracts this range from the string. `map` returns an array of whatever happens inside `{`and `}`, being `String`in our example. I. e. you get an array of strings each representing one of the regex matches.